# POSTing JSON with Association data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, rest

I am trying to send a POST request to a rails scaffold controller which contains a nested array representing records that need to be created and associated with the newly created parent.

Here is some example JSON:

```
{
    "plan_id":3,
    "weight":60,
    "exercise_sets": [
        {
            "created_at":"2012-06-13T14:55:57Z",
            "ended_at":"2012-06-13T14:55:57Z",
            "weight":"80.0",
            "repetitions":10,
            "exercise_id":1
        }
    ]
}
```

..and my models..

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exercise_sets, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :exercises, :through => :exercise_sets
end

class ExerciseSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exercise
  belongs_to :session
end
```

Is what I am attempting possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is certainly not impossible, though you may have to switch up your parameter naming a bit.

When you pass the JSON above to the controller, it either gets passed as parameters to a constructor:

```
Session.new(params[:session])
```

Or gets passed to the #update_attributes method on a persisted Session instance:

```
@session = Session.find(params[:id])
@session.update_attributes(params[:session])
```

Both the constructor and #update_attributes methods turn parameters like "plan_id" into assigment method calls.  That is,

```
@session.update_attributes(:plan_id => "1")
```

Turns into (inside the #update_attributes method):

```
@session.plan_id = "1"
```

So, this works for your plan_id and weight attributes, because you have both #plan_id= and #weight= setter methods.  You also have an #exercise_sets= method given to you by `has_many :exercise_sets`.  However, the #exercise_sets= method expects ExerciseSet objects, *not ExerciseSet attributes*.

Rails is capable of doing what you are trying to do via the #accepts_nested_attributes_for class method.  Try this:

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exercise_sets, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :exercises, :through => :exercise_sets

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercise_sets
end
```

This sets up (metaprograms) an #exercise_sets_attributes= method for you.  So just modify your JSON to:

```
{
    "plan_id":3,
    "weight":60,
    "exercise_sets_attributes": [
        {
            "created_at":"2012-06-13T14:55:57Z",
            "ended_at":"2012-06-13T14:55:57Z",
            "weight":"80.0",
            "repetitions":10,
            "exercise_id":1
        }
    ]
}
```

More info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: That's just what I need :) - one question, I've added the above to my model and changed the json I'm sending to call exercise_sets_attributes do I need to alter my controller? It doesn't appear to be creating the associated records!

Comment: ..to clarify, associated exercise_sets don't already exist, i.e. no exercise_set_id will be passed so these records will also need to be created.

Comment: You might need to namespace your JSON as well.  Rails will expect your JSON to look like:

{"session": {<your JSON from above} }

If you look at your server logs you should see:
Started POST to <your URL>
  Processing by SessionsController
  Parameters: {"sessions" => {"plan_id" => 3, "weight" => 80 ....}

What you don't want to see is:
Started POST to <your URL>
  Processing by SessionsController
  Parameters: {"plan_id" => 3, "weight" => 80 ....}

Comment: Hmm, switching to {"session": ...} gives me a 500 error, {"sessions": ...} creates a new record with no attributes, what I had before seems to work most correctly (still missing the association though)?

Comment: Could you possibly  copy and paste the 500 from your server logs?

Comment: I suspect the controller has something like Session.new(params[:session]), which has data when you pass {"session"...}, and has no data when you pass {"sessions"...}.  {"sessions"...} therefore results in a record with no data being created.  The 500 might mean you are actually assigning attributes.  In a Rails 3.2 app, you could be getting mass assignment security errors.

Comment: This is what I get using my original json i.e {"plan_id":3,"weight":"60.0","exercise_sets_attributes":[..], ...} http://pastebin.com/gmwYp6hV

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly possible, you just have to add the following line to your `Session` model:

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercise_sets, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:exercise_id].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

Now, when your controller does `Session.new(params[:session])`, Rails will build (or update) the `Session` *and* the related `ExerciceSet`(s).

Please review the `:reject_if` clause. That's where you define which records will be created and which will not.

This are the basics, but Ryan Bates explains the nested model forms perfectly (as always) in [this screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1).